# how to restore complex objects from checkpoint in tensor flow for prediction on new data by restore checkpoints

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am working on a Tensorflow Model. Here I have created a custom class where the model is being built. Below is the code for training.

```
    sess = tf.Session(config=session_conf)
    with sess.as_default():
        model = EntityAttentionLSTM(
            sequence_length=train_x.shape[1],
            num_classes=train_y.shape[1],
            vocab_size=len(vocab_processor.vocabulary_),
            embedding_size=FLAGS.embedding_size,
            pos_vocab_size=len(pos_vocab_processor.vocabulary_),
            pos_embedding_size=FLAGS.pos_embedding_size,
            hidden_size=FLAGS.hidden_size,
            num_heads=FLAGS.num_heads,
            attention_size=FLAGS.attention_size,
            use_elmo=(FLAGS.embeddings == 'elmo'),
            l2_reg_lambda=FLAGS.l2_reg_lambda)

            for train_batch in train_batches:
                train_bx, train_by, train_btxt, train_be1, train_be2, 
                train_bp1, train_bp2 = zip(*train_batch)
                feed_dict = {
                    model.input_x: train_bx,
                    model.input_y: train_by,
                    model.input_text: train_btxt,
                    model.input_e1: train_be1,
                    model.input_e2: train_be2,
                    model.input_p1: train_bp1,
                    model.input_p2: train_bp2,
                    model.emb_dropout_keep_prob: 
                    FLAGS.emb_dropout_keep_prob,
                    model.rnn_dropout_keep_prob: 
                    FLAGS.rnn_dropout_keep_prob,
                    model.dropout_keep_prob: FLAGS.dropout_keep_prob
            }
            _, step, summaries, loss, accuracy = sess.run(
                [train_op, global_step, train_summary_op, model.loss, model.accuracy], feed_dict)
            train_summary_writer.add_summary(summaries, step)
```

While this runs okay, if I have to load the checkpoint and restore the model, how would the prediction logic work? How to restore object of a class? Please help